# How do I optimize filtering in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have here a filter for AngularJS. Is there any better way for this?

```
 return function (data, selected) {
        var result = [];
        if (selected[0] == 'All Types') {
            result = data;
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < selected.length; j++) {
                    if (data[i].Type == selected[j]) {
                        result.push(data[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    };
```

Comment: I think no need of array `selected` here. Store selected value in data record. Can you update HTML and full code?

Comment: If there is only one that can match the selected, you can use a `continue` in the if block

Answer (score 0):

```
return function (data, selected) {
        var result = [];
        if (selected[0] == 'All Types') {
            result = data;
        }
        else {
           result=data.filter(x=>selected.indexOf(x.Type)>-1);
        }

        return result;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use data for selected value. I am assuming selected value is in data[i].selected.

```
return function (data) {
    var result = [];
    if (data[0].selected == 'All Types') {
        result = data;
    }
    else {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].Type == data[i].selected) {
                result.push(data[i]);                    
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

We can use filters

```
return function (data) {
    if (data[0].selected == 'All Types') {
        return data;
    }
    else {
        return data.filter(function (item) {
            return item.Type == item.selected;
        });
    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously this is using lodash, but native methods can be substituted:

```
return (data, selected) => {
  return 
    _.first(selected) === 'All Types' ? data :
    _.reduce(data, (sum, value, key) => {
      if (_.includes(selected, value.Type)) {
        sum.push(value);
      }
      return sum;
    }, []);
}
```